# Angular2 provide common logger to imported modules

Tags: angular, typescript, module

I want to make a module A which depends on a module B, but let the user provide a logger to both through A.

In other words

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleB.forRoot( /* use loggerLikeConsole from below */ )
  ],
  declarations: [
  ],
  exports: [
  ]
})
export class ModuleA {
  static forRoot(loggerLikeConsole: Console): ModuleWithProviders {
    //...
  }
}
```

Can this be done? It seems like it should be possible. Maybe I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module B should have the logger service in it's `providers:[]` declaration. The logger service would then be available in Module A upon importing B.

Services are shared across the entire application. So it doesn't matter whether you declare the service within a child or parent module. It will be available throughout the application. Exceptions are in the case of lazy-loaded modules, in which case you should add the service in the `providers` declaration of the lazy-loaded module also.

You can also try [angular2-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-logger), which we can import into application for logging.